# Git Post Hook to Kick Off Jenkins Job

Tags: java, spring, git, jenkins

I would like to setup a post hook in git to kick off a jenkins job everytime someone does a push to the git server. The issue is that some of the projects are on Linux, some are on windows and others on mac.

Everytime someone does a push into my git repo I would like the following code called:

```
cURL http://jenkins:8080/job/WebComm%20-%20Common%20Project%20for%20Communications/build?token=webcomm
```

But if I am right this will NOT work on the windows users right?

can someone please tell me if I am right and how can I get around this?

I made a post-receive file with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl "http://jenkins:8080/job/WebComm%20-%20Common%20Project%20for%20Communications/build?token=webcomm"
```

but the job is not getting kicked off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it as a server-side post-receive hook and it won't matter what the user is using. It will be what the server is running which matters.

Read about all the hooks [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Using this as a post-recieve hook should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl http://jenkins:8080/job/WebComm%20-%20Common%20Project%20for%20Communications/build?token=webcomm
```

Comment: I tried putting cURL http://jenkins:8080/job/WebComm%20-%20Common%20Project%20for%20Communications/build?token=webcomm in the post-receive but nothing happends

Comment: Did you write exactly cURL? the command is lower case. Added a hook to the answer which I believe should work, if the curl command is available on the server that is.

Comment: yes I did that and I also chmod u+x the file but do I need to do a push to the server with some option?

Comment: I added it and curl is on the server but its not getting kicked off on the server side?

Comment: It should kick in automatically. If you run the hook manually on the server, does it work?

Comment: my hook is not on the server... I dont know why my hooks are not getting pushed up to the server. I had the SA create the hook on the server and everything works but can someone please tell me how to create the hooks withouot the SA

Comment: You cannot push hooks from client to server. That would be a major security issue... Your SA must create them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on github, you can take advantage of their web hooks feature. It is quite reliable.

If not, you can use the [server-side hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-3.html#Server-Side-Hooks) on your own server.

Comment: I believe that GitHubs web hooks are more or less an exposure of the to server-side hooks, in a more controlled form.

Comment: I tried putting cURL http://jenkins:8080/job/WebComm%20-%20Common%20Project%20for%20Communications/build?token=webcomm in the post-receive but nothing happends.